# Dedekind Cut Proof Question

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on this proof:

Let A,B ⊆ Q be Dedekind cuts.
Suppose that 0 ∈ Q−A and 0 ∈ Q−B. The set {r ∈ Q | r = ab for some a ∈ A and b ∈ B} is a Dedekind cut.

I know I need to satisfy the three parts of this definition:

Definition 1.6.1.
Let A ⊆ Q be a set.
The set A is a Dedekind cut if the following three properties hold:

- A is not equal to Ø and A is not equal to Q.
- Let x ∈ A. If y ∈ Q and x ≥ y, then y ∈ A.
- Let x ∈ A. Then there is some y ∈ A such that x < y.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false.

Define $S:=\{r|r=ab\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,a\in{}A\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,b\in{}B\}$. I claim $S$ is not a cut.

**Proof**:

Choose arbitrary $a'\in{}A$ and $b'\in{}B$. Then $a',b'<0$ and $a'\cdot{}b'>0$. Thus $0\notin{}S$, violating the second part of the definition of Dedekind Cuts.